# Problem with WATIJ

Tags: java, automated-tests, watij

I have logged in to a website by using [WATIJ](http://watij.com/) jar file in java. Now I want to get the page source (HTML code) of the webpage that appeared after login.

I have IE instance already.

Comment: Did you try any code for that? if yes, please provide your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the .html() method?

Or if you search for something particular, you can search for the specific HtmlElement

but again with some code,  or with info about what you have try, that will help us to give you a better answer

Comment: .html() method is working fine.
Now I have one problem. All orkut pages has one small chat window in the bottom-left of the page so when I try to get the source code through ie.html() it returns the source code of that small chat window and I want the source code of the page on which that chat window appears.
Can you help me please.

Thanks in advance.